# Codeception: Can't connect to WebDriver at http://chrome:9515/wd/hub

Tags: selenium, codeception

I tried to set up a very bare bones Codeception framework to see what the differences are between it and my enterprise framework for my own learning. My POC framework was running great until I tried to get it with docker and I don't know much about docker. I kept getting this error when trying to run with any docker command:

```
  [ConnectionException] Can't connect to WebDriver at http://chrome:9515/wd/hub. Make sure that ChromeDriver, GeckoDriver or Selenium Server is running.
```

So I ripped out docker-compose.yml completely and tried to run tests the normal way:

```
  ./chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub
```

and then in another tab

```
  ./vendor/bin/codecept run -vvv
```

But now I get the error from before! "[ConnectionException] Can't connect to WebDriver at http://chrome:9515/wd/hub. Make sure that ChromeDriver, GeckoDriver or Selenium Server is running.  "

At this point, I would just be happy to get my framework back to running without docker. I have tried googling and other SO answers and they don't seem to help, I don't have anything weird in my bash or zsh profile. My other terminal says "ChromeDriver was started successfully." I shouldn't have a firewall. It was working before.

My acceptance.suite.yml is:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
  - WebDriver:
    url: http://localhost
    window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
    port: 9515
    browser: chrome
    host: chrome
    capabilities:
      "goog:chromeOptions": # additional chrome options
  - \Helper\Acceptance
```

Comment: java -jar "/path/to/selenium-server-standalone-xxx.jar" Have you run this before running your tests.

Comment: Host chrome may exist in your docker-compose setup, but it definitelly doesn't exist when you run chromedriver in a normal way. Please share your docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Already deleted the file as part of troubleshooting, unfortunately. Also not running any java commands as its a php project and worked fine before without that part